# Do I have to specify actions in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby, authentication, devise, dry, ruby-on-rails-4.2

While I'm reading [Rails 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/bigg2/), I'm trying to implement my own application, so it doesn't look same as in the book.
The book's corresponding commit is [Section 7.2.3: Only admins can create or delete projects](https://github.com/rubysherpas/r4ia_examples/tree/62a567315dd642f31ea8b0e7d4040dad9d920b7f/ticketee)

In my case, **admins can only delete the item** (`item` corresponds to the `project` in the book.).

My repo https://github.com/tenzan/shop and deployed http://ichiba-demo.herokuapp.com/

The rule I want to apply is:

1. A regular user (you can login with `staff@example.com/password`) can do everything except `destroy` action.
2. Admin (`admin@example.com/password`) only can `destroy`.

To realise that I have:

In `admin/items_controller.rb`:

```
    class Admin::ItemsController < Admin::ApplicationController

      def destroy
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        @item.destroy

        flash[:notice] = 'Item has been deleted.'
        redirect_to items_path
      end

      private

      def item_params
        params.require(:item).permit(:name, :quantity)
      end

    end
```

In `controllers/items_controller.rb`:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Item has been created.'
      redirect_to @item
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Item has not been created.'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

    if @item.update(item_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Item has been updated.'
      redirect_to @item
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Item has not been updated.'
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:alert] = 'The item could not be found.'
    redirect_to items_path
  end

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :quantity)
  end
end
```

In `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    root 'application#index'

    resources :items, only: :destroy
  end

  devise_for :users
  root 'items#index'

  resources :items, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :new, :create] do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

**Questions:**

1. Do I have to specify actions in the `routes.rb`, as I already have specified who can use what actions in their corresponding controllers? I didn't notice any change when I remove them from the `routes.rb`...
2. Am I violating DRY concept, when I specify actions in 2 places, i.e. in the `routes.rb` and `controllers/items_controllers.rb` ?

*I'll be happy if you point out other places to improve to meet best practice.*

PS: The subject maybe vague, please feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're not violating DRY directly, you're muddying up the REST architecture by moving a single entity's actions to different controllers. You don't need a specific controller or namespace for admins - you just need to assert that the user is an administrator before proceeding with the delete action.

Since you have already added the `admin` column to your devise model, you can move the delete action to `ItemsController`

```
def destroy
  if current_user.try(:admin?)

    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy

    flash[:notice] = 'Item has been deleted.'
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Only admins can delete items.'
  end
  redirect_to items_path
end
```

Your routes would be cleaner since your admin namespace would be used only for user moderation. The only route for items would be:

```
  resources :items do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Comment: I assume, you mean there's no need to create namespace for `admin/items`? Correct? I think I will still need to create `admin/users` namespace to add and remove users...

Comment: Ah, yes - you'll need it for user moderation. I was thinking that you had created the namespace just for admins to modify items. Updated the answer

Comment: I'm testing now and get back once I finish.

Comment: It seems we need `else` condition here, otherwise it will complain that it can't find template for `destroy` action:

      def destroy
    
        if current_user.try(:admin?)
          @item.destroy
          flash[:notice] = 'Item has been deleted.'
        else
          flash[:alert] = 'Only admin can delete an item.'
        end
        redirect_to items_url
      end

Comment: What if we put `redirect_to items_path` out of `if condition` ? `DRY` concept ;)

Comment: @oscar yeah, I refactored the answer to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to specify actions in the routes.rb, as I already have
>   specified who can use what actions in their corresponding controllers?

Yes. For instance, if you'd have only one action in `items_controller.rb` controller (let say `show`), and left

```
resources :items do # no specified actions
  #...
end
```

in `routes.rb` it would generate all routes for items controller (for `new`, `create`, `edit`, `destroy`, `update` etc). But specifying actions in `routes.rb` you limit generated routes to only needed.

> Am I violating DRY concept, when I specify actions in 2 places, i.e.
>   in the routes.rb and controllers/items_controllers.rb ?

No. Because you actually specify actions in controller, in `routes.rb` you only specify **routes**.

> I'll be happy if you point out other places to improve to meet best
>   practice.

This line:

```
resources :items, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :new, :create] # better to use %i() notation, eg only: %i(index show edit update new create)
```

could be written as:

```
resources :items, except: :destroy
```

Regarding your admin user - to allow only him to `destroy`, just check if current_user is admin. If you'll have more, than one action which is allowed to be performed by only admin, you can create before_action in controller:

```
before_action :check_admin?, only: %i(destroy another_action)

private

def check_admin?
  # your logic to check, if user is admin
end
```

You can also be interested in going through [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: Spasibo, Andrei! I also voted up for your answer as well, as you gave me new tips. ;)